# Sum Receipt Amount & QTY that Include specific Item No which is 16776 in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

Sum Receipt Amount & QTY that Include specific Item No which is 16776 in SQL

```
 Receipt No_              item     Amount      QTY
 00000P2315000011636      16776     15           0
 00000P2315000011636      16777     188          10
 00000P2315000011636      16780     495          11
 00000P2315000011665      16813     498          30
 00000P2315000011668      16816    8,307         31
 00000P2315000011669      16817    1,322         32
 00000P2335000008315      16776      15          20
 00000P2335000008315      16881     2,001        21
 00000P2335000008315      16885     1,020        22
```

I need Answer to be

```
Receipt No_           Net Amount    QTY
00000P2315000011636      698         21
00000P2335000008315      3036        63
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Sub query:

Try below Query:

```
SELECT Receipt as 'Receipt No_',SUM(Amount) AS 'Net Amount', SUM(QYT) AS QTY
FROM Your_Table 
WHERE Receipt IN (
                  SELECT  Receipt 
                  FROM Your_Table 
                  WHERE Item=16776 
                )
GROUP BY Receipt;
```

Output:

```
Receipt No_           Net Amount    QTY
-----------------------------------------------
00000P2315000011636     698          21
00000P2335000008315     3036         63
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0582732e209d5f21dbd1df82e7c8fbe2)

Comment: oh great. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  if you feel it correct solution for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just consider item 16776, for calculating the SUM, GROUP BY, you can do the following.

```
SELECT ReceiptNo, SUM(Amount), SUM(Qty)
FROM
(SELECT ReceiptNo, CASE WHEN item = 16776 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END AS 16776Amount,
CASE WHEN item = 16776 THEN QTY ELSE 0 END AS 16776QTY
FROM Table1
) AS t
GROUP BY ReceiptNo
```

Your answer includes all items. If you consider all items then 16776 is included by default, as it is one of the items.

```
SELECT ReceiptNo, SUM(Amount), SUM(Qty)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ReceiptNo
```